# Change font family of object using its id

Tags: javascript, css, fonts

I need to change my font family of specific object using its id

Any suggestions how I do it?

```
<script>
    var day = new Date();
    var today = day.getDate();
    var lys = today * 16;
    var heode = 505 - lys;

    if (today == 24){
    document.getElementById("chistmas").innerHTML ="Merry Christmas"
    }   
    else {
        let remainingdays = 24 - today;
        document.getElementById("chistmas").innerHTML = "there are " + remainingdays + " days until christmas"
    }
    document.getElementsByClassName("light")[0].style.height=heode+"px"   
</script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("chistmas").style.fontFamily = 'courier';`

Comment: Exactly like you did at the bottom of your code, just instead of height you write fontFamily = "Arial"

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like below:

```
document.getElementById("chistmas").innerHTML ="<label style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'>Merry Christmas</label>"
```

or,

```
label.yourClassName {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

document.getElementById("chistmas").innerHTML ="<label class='yourClassName'>Merry Christmas</label>"
```

Comment: Please expand your answer by explaining what the code you posted is doing and why it provides an answer to the asked question.

Comment: The question is edited, before it was 'How to apply font family in innerHTML', for which my answer

Answer (score -1):

If you know the selector will only match one class:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("className")[0].style.fontFamily = "New Font Family";
```

If you need to modify multiple elements then you need to loop over the result of `document.getElementsByClassName("className")`